# Disable custom Html Helper element

Tags: jquery, html

We have a custom Html Helper element which acts like autocomplete control.
I am trying to disable the whole control in jQuery based on a checkbox uncheck event and not able to disable the whole control. 
Can you pleas suggest what might be the issue ?

Here is the HTML for the control

```
 <div class="f-form-field">
              <label>Restrict User Code:</label>
              <a cboxheight="450" cboxwidth="650" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default f-form-popup" href="/ParagonLS/Controls/UserTypePartial.mvc/Index/0?controlId=SearchRestrictedUserCodes&amp;multiselect=True" tabindex="-1" title="User Codes">
                 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="ui-helper-reset acfb-holder SearchRestrictedUserCodes" style="">
                 <li>
                    <li class="acfb-data">
                    <span title="REALTOR">REALTOR</span>
                    <img class="p" rel="1" src="/ParagonLS/Scripts/autocompletefb/delete.gif" title="Remove">
                    </li>
                    <li class="acfb-data">
                    <span title="OFFICE ASSISTANT">OFFICE ASSISTANT</span>
                    <img class="p" rel="6" src="/ParagonLS/Scripts/autocompletefb/delete.gif" title="Remove">
                    </li>
                    <input cbheight="450" cbwidth="650" class="ac_input acfb-input acf" data="Name" desc="Code" extraparams="{&quot;multiple&quot;:true}" id="SearchRestrictedUserCodes" name="SearchRestrictedUserCodes" type="text" url="/ParagonLS/Services/UserType.svc/json/v1/Autocomplete" autocomplete="off">

                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

I can add disable attribute to the input #SearchRestrictedUserCodes, but it does not disable the entire control / ul.

```
$("#SearchRestrictedUserCodes").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Tried disabling the parent of this input control, but not able to do so.

```
$("#SearchRestrictedUserCodes").parent.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. As is `.parent.attr('disabled', 'disabled');`.

Comment: you are right. tried .parent().attr('disabled', 'disabled'); but still no change

Comment: You need to fix the HTML issue too. Most browsers will try and fix it for you but that can result in unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Its not

```
$("#SearchRestrictedUserCodes").parent.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

but

```
$("#SearchRestrictedUserCodes").parent().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: You are right per the syntax,and I can see the 'disabled' attribute attached to the parent element. But the whole control as such is not disabled for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinRohan pointed out, `parent` is a function and needs parentheses after it.  Additionally, you defined `SearchRestrictedUserCodes` as a CSS class, not an element ID, so the line would be:

```
$(".SearchRestrictedUserCodes").parent().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Alternatively, you could make `SearchRestrictedUserCodes` an ID instead:

```
<ul id="SearchRestrictedUserCodes" class="ui-helper-reset acfb-holder" style="">
```